# Find battery usage of single application programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Find out the battery usage of an application in `iOS`` devices.Is is possible to do this, if it is possible how to estimate the battery usage?

Answer (score 2):

There's not a way to access this with code.

The easiest way to test it is like this:

1) Charge up your device to 100%. Leave it playing music until the battery dies. Keep track of how long that took.

2) Recharge the device to 100%, leave it playing music AND running your app until the battery dies.

This gives you some idea (at least compared to just playing music) how much power is consumed by your app.

Comment: How to programmatically get battery usage for an application ?

Comment: You can't. There's a reason this was asked well over a year ago, and mine is still the only answer.

Answer (score -2):

First enable the isBatteryMonitoringEnabled property of the current device, like this:

***UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true***

You can now read the current battery level as a value between 0.0 (flat) and 1.0 (fully charged) using this:

***let level = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel***

If you want to be notified every time the battery level changes you can register for the **UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange** notification (sent up to once a minute), and you can also register for **UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange** notification to see when the charge state changes. Both of those require **isBatteryMonitoringEnabled** to be enabled.